# JavaScript Joi error Property does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, typescript, backend, joi

I am trying to validate my `req.body` from my API using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi):

> Property does not exist on type

Here is my code:

```
const idScheme = Joi.string().required();
const updatedBioScheme = Joi.object({
  bio: Joi.string()
      .min(3)
      .required(),
});

export async function
updatedBio(req: Request, res: Response,) {
  try {
    const uid = req.query.uid;
    const {err, val} = updatedBioScheme.validate(req.body);
    const {error, value} = idScheme.validate(uid);
    if (error) {
      res.status(400).json({error: "Invalid uid parameter"});
      return;
    } else if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    const userId = value;
    const {bio}= val;
    const inject = myContainer.get<ProfileServicesRepository>(TYPES.ProfileServices);
    const data = await inject.updateBio(userId, bio);
    if (data == undefined) {
      return res.status(400).json({error: "User not available yet!!"});
    }
    return res.status(200).json({data, message: "Sucessful"});
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({error, message: "error"});
  }
}
```

I am getting the error from this  `const {err, val} = updatedBioScheme.validate(req.body);`

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have imported 'joi' correctly

Comment: yes i imported joi well but the idScheme is not given error... only the updatedBioscheme that is given error. @A.Sevi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figure out the error, so i just  to a value

```
 const {error: err, value: val} = updatedBioScheme.validate(req.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Joi doc you have `value`, `error`. Instead you try to extract `err` and `val` which are non-existent on the object and TypeScript knows it.

Comment: yes, if you check the code above, you will see that for req.query.uid; i think if i <T> it, it will see thesame as equal.. one sec